# Does the Radeon HD 8570M work with Ubuntu (Saucy/Trusty)? (no hybrid)

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I'm planning to buy a new computer. It uses a AMD A8 processor with a Radeon HD 8570M. I've read lots of discussions on how to get this card work using Ubuntu or Mint. However, all of them were talking about usage of the HD 8570M as an additional graphics card and a Intel HD 4000 chip working as hybrid.

Now this device just uses the HD 8570M. Does anyone of you have experience with this or knows where to find help?

Thanks in advance

---

Computer model:

HP ProBook 455 G1 (CPU: AMD A8-4500M)

Got a SuSe installed but I want a free (means $0, not the "free-kind of free") OS and want to keep on using Ubuntu or Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought the computer and after a few issues it is working well now.

Initially I had problems with the screen brightness when using fglrx, but it is fixed in later kernel versions.